# Remove event handler if I don't know the original selector used to create this handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to unbind the event handler from the element.

The handler is created by a 3-rd party plugin and I don't want a behavior it produces.

Correct me if I wrong but `off()` and `unbind()` functions can be used only with an original selector.

The problem is that I don't know this selector or this selector may change in a future.

How can I remove event handler without using original selector?

Comment: This sounds to me like a problem you shouldn't be having. Is there a way to interface with the 3rd party code and get it to change it's behaviour?

Comment: You should just be able to call `unbind()` on any element (not using original selector) and it will unbind all events attached to it - from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/): *In the simplest case, with no arguments, .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the elements.*

Comment: By the way, if you are wanting to remove all styling and other effects of the third party plugin, you may need to call it's destroy method of the plugin (if it has one) rather than unbind as unbind won't undo any styling changes - it will only remove any events bound to the element

Comment: I don't want to unbind all. Only click. I have been able to add and remove 'click' handler using .off('click'), but it does nothing to handler of the plugin.

Comment: By the way, is the handler really attached to the element? Isn't it attached to parent?

Comment: Pretty sure it is. I see it Chrome's Event Listeners tab with ancestors disabled.

Comment: Did you try to use the suggested ** (double asterisk) selector as suggested in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove or update an event handler for an element you must have *some* way of identifying or referencing that element. Otherwise you're effectively trying to say "remove the event handler of a button, but I won't tell you which one".

Alternatively, you could try overwriting the handler itself, with a function that does nothing.

Comment: I just say the selector I will use won't 100% match the original one. For example: $('form input#name') and just $(input#name).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation http://api.jquery.com/off/ mentions an example without using the original selector.

Calling without a selector will remove all handlers matching the event / namespace.

If you can target the handler with the event name and/or namespace, you don't need to know the selector.

Comment: I see the opposite thing : "A selector which should match the one originally passed to .on() when attaching event handlers."

Comment: Only when specified. From the doc: "When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed." See the last example.